# React fade & click through on hover

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

Pretty stumped on this one. I have a component that fades out when hovered upon and fades in when the mouse leaves the component. That much is simple.

But I am searching for a solution that allows the user to click through while hovering. The faded in/out component is a HUD type component that will never need to be actually clicked on and is for informational purposes.

I've tried various forms of `pointer-events: none` to no avail. That being said, I've tried the following in my component as well, to no avail:

```
const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    const overlay = document.querySelector('.timer-overlay') as HTMLElement;
    if (overlay) {
      console.log('should pass thru!');
      overlay.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    }
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    const overlay = document.querySelector('.timer-overlay') as HTMLElement;
    if (overlay) {
      console.log('should NOT pass thru!');
      overlay.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="flex timer-overlay"
      onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
    >
      (Other components here...)
    </div>
  );
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. User should be able to click the child components by default.

Comment: I think I miscommunicated. I need to be able to click things behind the faded component.